# When connecting to Grafana I get an error 502

Tags: .net, grafana

I use the [SimpleJson plugin](https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource) to connect.
But I get error 502 ([PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7TeC.jpg))

I add CORS in my startup file:

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
```

And I create endpoints for GET (/) and POSTS (/query, /annotations, /search) as written in the documentation in [GitHub docs](https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource):

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Grafana
{
    [ApiController]
    public class BugsMonitoringController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("/")]
        public void Empty()
        {
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("query")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Query()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("[{\"columns\":[{\"text\":\"Time\",\"type\":\"time\"},{\"text\":\"Country\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"text\":\"Number\",\"type\":\"number\"}],\"rows\":[[1234567,\"SE\",182],[1234567,\"DE\",282],[1234567,\"US\",382]],\"type\":\"table\"}]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("search")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Search()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("[ { \"text\" :\"upper_25\", \"value\": 1}, { \"text\" :\"upper_75\", \"value\": 2} ]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };            
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("annotations")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Annotation()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent("[{\"text\":\"text shown in body\",\"title\":\"Annotation Title\",\"isRegion\":true,\"time\":\"timestamp\",\"timeEnd\":\"timestamp\",\"tags\":[\"tag1\"]}]", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };            
        }

    }
```

Indicated server address in DataSource ([PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCkqF.png))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem
When I wrote URL in JSON plugin I used localhost:5000. Need to use your local address, for example: 192.168.1.10. And change "applicationUrl" in launchSettings.json